# Как изменить дату создания файла на C# Onedrive SDK

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

Как на C# изменить дату создания файла на Onedrive SDK?

```
string[] _scopes = { "onedrive.readwrite", "onedrive.appfolder" };
IOneDriveClient _OneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(_scopes);
await _OneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();

Item item = await _OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children["mydb.db"].Request().GetAsync();
Item newitem = new Item { CreatedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(2013, 2, 15, 2, 3, 4, 0, new TimeSpan()) };
var ri = await _OneDriveClient.Drive.Items[item.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(newitem);
```

Последняя строка вызывает исключение accessdenied.
Чего здесь не хватает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дата создания (и изменения) доступна только для чтения. Для этих целей (например, при синхронизации) следует использовать [FileSystemInfo](https://dev.onedrive.com/facets/filesysteminfo_facet.htm). В данном примере `newitem` следует заменить на

```
Item newitem = new Item
{
  FilesystemInfo = new FileSystemInfo
  {
    CreatedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(2013, 2, 15, 2, 3, 4, 0, new TimeSpan()),
  },
};
```